# Entered CLLocationDegrees value yields erroneous value. Why?

Tags: swift, numbers, cllocation

I'm trying to set a MKCircle coordinate and am having trouble creating the 'coordinate'.

I've tried setting specific CLLocationDegrees attributes but the entered numeral is not interpreted correctly. 
For example, an entered '-37' yields 2.1974599073494367E-314.

Why is this happening; and how do I fix it?
[image]

```
(lldb) p lat
(CLLocationDegrees) $R0 = 2.1974599073494367E-314
(lldb) p long
(CLLocationDegrees) $R1 = 2.2149668507855847E-314
```

---

This appears to work:

```
let gLocationCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.813611, 144.963056)
```

```
(lldb) p gLocationCoordinate
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) $R2 = (latitude = -37.813611000000002, longitude = 144.96305599999999)
```

---

Comment: Better add `println(lat)` to you code, I would not always trust the debugger output. Could also be caused by the optimizer.

Comment: I've added println() per your suggestion (see updated query, above).  But I'm not getting output.  Curious.

Comment: Okay... I had braked within viewDidLoad().  Allowing it to continue produced the println().

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the debugger. As Martin notes, it works fine with `println()`:

```
let lat : CLLocationDegrees = -37
let long : CLLocationDegrees = 144

println("Lat: \(lat) Long: \(long)")
// Output: "Lat: -37.0 Long: 144.0"
```

I'd file a radar against lldb.

Comment: (Although, I can't reproduce your problem in Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d))

Comment: I moved the code later into the load, to viewDidAppear() and it worked.  Is this a bug?   Worked in Xcode 6.1 & 6.2 beta.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee I believe it's a bug, but only in the debugger (It shouldn't affect the actual behavior of your app.)

Comment: This code is the Swift version of an ObjC code that I got from the Internet.  I'm not getting ANY overlay... it's buggy.  So I officially filed a bug report w/Apple; containing both zipped myCode (Swift) & demo (ObjC): Bug #:19062522

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code from viewDidLoad() to viewDidAppear() and it worked.

But need I do that?

[image]